# Conditional cell for incorrect value excluding blanks

Tags: excel, excel-formula, conditional-formatting

Trying to define a conditional cell that highlights the value in A1 when that value is not equal to the sum of values in B1 and C1, but excluding when B1 and/or C1 is blank

In the mockup below, only A3 should be highlighted.

I have tried with numerous formulas, none of which works correctly:

```
=SUMIF(B1:C1,"<>",B1:C1)
=IF(OR(ISBLANK(B1),ISBLANK(C1)),"",B1:C1)
=SUM(IF(COUNTBLANK(B1:C1),"",SUM(B1:C1))B1:C1)
```

[image: Conditional cell]

Many thanks for indicating my error!

Comment: You want to highlight A only when B and C are **not** blank and A is not equal to B+C so something like `AND(B1<>"",C1<>"",A1<>B1+C1)` should work for you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to highlight A only when B and C **are not** blank **and** A **is not** equal to B+C so something like `AND(B1<>"",C1<>"",A1<>B1+C1)` should work for you